# Removing Session cookie in Flask & Flask-Login

Tags: python, cookies, flask, flask-login

We have a requirement from a client that users should have to authenticate every session.

A session cookie should do the trick (it's what they're meant for, after all) but Chrome, Firefox, and Safari [**will persist**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069339/flask-login-how-to-force-firefox-chrome-to-remove-session-cookie-when-tab-is-cl) these session cookies if the user has selected "reopen last tabs on startup" in their browser options.

Our client does not like this and would prefer us just to expire the cookies really quickly, like 30 min (the site is not intended for prolonged use).

I'm able to set up "remember" cookies via Flask-Login, but the issue is that even when I do, Flask-Login *is still setting a session cookie*, meaning that even after the permanent cookie expires, the session one is retained and the user is *still* authenticated.

How can I completely disable the session cookie in the first place?

Comment: have you tried this?? https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#fresh-logins

Comment: `When their session is destroyed and they are logged back in with a “remember me” cookie...` - this relies on sessions being destroyed, which is the exact issue that we were facing (sessions aren't destroyed in certain browsers) and trying to solve by not using sessions in the first place...

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Removed the "... inadequate" line because it was too subjective ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to handle this on the server side, because as you've pointed out, you're not able to 100% control the cookie behaviour on the client side.

Essentially you want to change your `user_loader` callback function to check the user's activity (either when they were last seen or when they last logged in).

For example:

```
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):

    user = User.query.get(id)

    if not user:
        return None

    minutes = 30

    if user.last_seen < (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=minutes)):
        # Session has timed out
        return None

    return user
```